# Json calling rest url to grails gsp page

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-controller, grails3

I have tried to find an example who shows my how to render a rest url like this : http://localhost:8080/api/Cars in a gsp page.

I have tried every example people provides. No one of them is totally correct or its not working for my.

Some of the things i have tried is grails.converters.JSON.parse, Jsonslurper, HTTPBuilder.

Can someone give me a step by step introduction on how to just make a call from this url: "http://localhost:8080/api/Cars" to an controller who renders the json to gsp page.

By the way im using grails 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to get value of http://localhost:8080/api/Cars and display the data to gsp page? Or you want to display the data of http://localhost:8080/api/Cars as json?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for asking and sorry for not being so clear. This step just fustrate me.

I have two applications. The url is from the first application and i am trying to call this url from the second application so i can show it in the gsp page

Comment: Please show us the current code that you have

Comment: I have added some code here. If you want i can show the other exampels also. This is the only one who gives something the others give error. 

https://jsfiddle.net/4nk203Le/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
def cars
def url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/Cars'

def httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url)
def response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)

cars = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
cars = new JsonSlurper().parseText(cars);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String jx = "http://localhost:8080/api/category";
def jsonObject = grails.converters.JSON.parse(jx)
```

jx is just a character string. Perhaps what you need is to convert that string into a URL, then use URL's getText() method to call that URL and get the response, which is what you want to parse. Perhaps something like:

```
def jsonObject = JSON.parse(jx.toURL().getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [REST client builder plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder?skipRedirect=true)

Then use like:

```
new RestBuilder().get( 'http://localhost:8080/api/Cars' ).json
```